# how can i plot a line on bar chart in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

```
H <- c(1,2,4,1,0,0,3,1,3)
M <- c("one","two","three","four","five")
barplot(H,names.arg=M,xlab="number",ylab="random",col="blue",
    main="bar chart",border="blue")
```

I want to add line on the bar chart , i don't know how to do it

like the one in blue

[image]

Comment: Should `M` have same lenght as `H`?

Comment: I know the answer: yes, it should.

Comment: I'm not sure what line you're referring to (the mean?), but you probably want `barplot(table(H), ...`. If you want a horizontal line at the mean, you can type: `abline(h=mean(H), lty=2, col="red"`.

Comment: Or `barplot(table(setNames(H,M)), ...)`.

Comment: I mean after plotting the bars I want to add a line that shows the shape of the bars, a curve I mean

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745860/add-geom-line-to-stacked-barplot-in-r/62746093#62746093)?

Comment: yes please , a curve on the bar chart  that show the shape of variation of values

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want this?

```
hist(H, breaks=-1:4, freq=FALSE, xaxt="n")
axis(side=1, at=seq(-0.5, 3.5), labels=M)
lines(density(H))
```

[image]

Comment: do you know please how can I do the same shape as in the picture I showed ?

Answer (score 0):

The graph in the question can be made with code following the lines of:

**1.** Table the `x` vector.

```
tbl <- table(H)
df1 <- as.data.frame(tbl)
```

**2.** With package `ggplot2`, built-in ways of fitting a line can be used.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(as.integer(Var1), Freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = stats::loess, 
              formula = y ~ x, 
              color = "blue", fill = "blue",
              alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

**Test data creation code.**

```
set.seed(2020)
f <- function(x) sin(x)^2*exp(x)
p <- f(seq(0, 2.5, by = 0.05))
p <- p/sum(p)
H <- sample(51, size = 1e3, prob = p, replace = TRUE)
```

## Edit

Here is a new graph, with the new data posted in comment. The data is at the end of this answer.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

Mdate <- as.Date(paste0(M, "/2020"), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
df1 <- data.frame(H, M = Mdate)


ggplot(df1, aes(M, H)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = stats::loess, 
              formula = y ~ x, 
              color = "blue", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.25,
              level = 0.5, span = 0.1) +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%d/%m"))
```

[image]

## New data

```
H <- c(1,2,4,1,0,0,3,1,3,3, 6,238,0,
       58,17,64,38,3,10,8, 10,11,13,
       7,25,11,12,13,28,44)  
M <- c("29/02","01/03","02/03","03/03",
       "04/03","05/03","06/03","07/03",
       "08/03", "09/03","10/03","11/03",
       "12/03","13/03","14/03","15/03",
       "16/03", "17/03","18/03","19/03",
       "20/03","21/03","22/03","23/03",
       "24/03", "25/03","26/03","27/03",
       "28/03","29/03")
```

Comment: H <- c(1,2,4,1,0,0,3,1,3,3,
       6,238,0,58,17,64,38,3,10,8,
       10,11,13,7,25,11,12,13,28,44) are the values of y axis and M <- c("29/02","01/03","02/03","03/03","04/03","05/03","06/03","07/03","08/03",
       "09/03","10/03","11/03","12/03","13/03","14/03","15/03","16/03",
       "17/03","18/03","19/03","20/03","21/03","22/03","23/03","24/03",
       "25/03","26/03","27/03","28/03","29/03") is the x axis, can you help me please with the code because I don't know how to make this bar chart as in the firt picture I showed